# divide a list with unknown number of elements

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a list of unknown number of elements in string value, I want to divide it to n subarray or lists (n could be any int, for example n=3), what is best way to do it?

note: the number of elements in each group is not necessary to be equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx) and [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) methods can help:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
int groupCount = 3;

var subLists = list.Select((s, i) => new {Str = s, Index = i}).
                    GroupBy(o => o.Index % groupCount, o => o.Str).
                    Select(coll => coll.ToList()).
                    ToList();
```

This code will result in `subLists` containing a list of three `List<string>` collections: `{"A", "D", "G"}`, `{"B", "E"}` and `{"C", "F"}`. In order to achieve that I based my grouping on element indices in the original list (there is an overload for `Select` method that lets you do that, see link above). You can use some other logic to select the key.

In my example `subLists` is a `List<List<string>>`. If you need an array, use `ToArray` where appropriate.

EDIT: using modulo operation for grouping may not be a good idea if you care about the way values are distributed between lists. Probably the better option is to do it this way:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G" };
int groupCount = 3;

int maxPerGroup = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)list.Count / groupCount);

var subLists = list.Select((s, i) => new {Str = s, Index = i}).
                    GroupBy(o => o.Index / maxPerGroup, o => o.Str).
                    Select(coll => coll.ToList()).
                    ToList();
```

This will produce the following result: `{"A", "B", "C"}`, `{"D", "E", "F"}`, `{"G"}` which may be more sane way to distribute the values.

Bottom line is, you can achieve what you need by using `GroupBy` and `Select` methods, just provide the correct grouping logic that is suitable for your domain.

Comment: what does => mean here?? and who do we access each sublist in this case？

Comment: @ikel: `=>` is a syntax for Lambda Expressions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), they are bread and butter of LINQ code. I assume you are not into LINQ yet. Maybe it's time to try? 101 LINQ Samples (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) is a good place to start.

Comment: i just noticed that based on your code, each group has max 3 elements and the number of group is not always 3

Comment: @ikel: oh, you're right! I had `o.Index % groupCount` in earlier revisions of my answers, that would ensure that the number of groups is 3, but the items would be grouped like this: `{"A", "D", "G"}`, `{"B", "E"}`, `{"C", "F"}`. Is it suitable for your needs? If not, what's the right way to distribute the values based on your domain?

Answer (score 0):

alternately, you can do it in linq like

```
var n = 4;
            var i = 0;
            var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
            var res = list.GroupBy(x => Math.Ceiling((double)++i / n)).Select(x=>x.Select(y=>y).ToList()).ToList();
            Console.Write(res);
```

write this in Console program or Linqpad and change values of n to see the effect